# Owl Carousel Not Showing Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I've my bootstrap website and it's work good ...
All JAVASCRIPT codes working except the owl carousel

here is the owl carousel code:

```
<section id="gallery" class="wow fadeInUp">
<div class="owl-carousel gallery-carousel">
<a href="img/gallery/1.png" class="venobox" data-gall="gallery-carousel"><img src="img/gallery/1.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="img/gallery/2.png" class="venobox" data-gall="gallery-carousel"><img src="img/gallery/2.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="img/gallery/3.png" class="venobox" data-gall="gallery-carousel"><img src="img/gallery/3.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="img/gallery/4.png" class="venobox" data-gall="gallery-carousel"><img src="img/gallery/4.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="img/gallery/5.png" class="venobox" data-gall="gallery-carousel"><img src="img/gallery/5.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="img/gallery/6.png" class="venobox" data-gall="gallery-carousel"><img src="img/gallery/6.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="img/gallery/7.png" class="venobox" data-gall="gallery-carousel"><img src="img/gallery/7.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="img/gallery/8.png" class="venobox" data-gall="gallery-carousel"><img src="img/gallery/8.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
</section>
```

The carousel showing only two images 
[image: The carousel showing only two images]

[Website Files Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cbjGNfXIeHPc92x8pOo5pFO-L4hAmaJz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: sorry for that but i think the problem is because of conflict between javascript files so i uploaded the whole website

Comment: It doesn't matter. Your question is up for closure for not posting your code within your question as I described before.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple just add style for the container like this.

```
<section id="gallery" class="wow fadeInUp animated" style="direction: ltr;">
```